# Selecting a row in DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I select a particular range of rows in a `DataGridView` programmatically at runtime?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Not tested, but I think you can do the following:

```
dataGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```

or you could do the following (but again: not tested):

```
dataGrid.SelectedRows.Clear();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    if(YOUR CONDITION)
       row.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Beware if your DataGridView is `read-only` - then `SelectedRows.Clear()` will not work.

Comment: Instead of SelectedRows.Clear() use the ClearSelection() method of the datagridview instance

Comment: @Furkan: That does not do the same thing. With `SelectedRows.Clear()` only the selected rows are cleared, but with `ClearSelection()` also the columns => column-selections are lost...

Comment: add one line of code `dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];`

Comment: @Timeless: the SelectionChanged event does not seem to be triggered when testing your suggestion.

Comment: @user2430797 I suspect we only set current cell `.CurrentCell` but not current row. if you want to trigger `SelectionChanged`, maybe you want to try `.Rows[index].Selected = true;` **note: not tested.**

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (((int)item.Cells["ImageWidth"].Value > 1000 || (int)item.Cells["ImageHeigth"].Value > 1000) && (bool)item.Cells["Exists"].Value == false)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[item.Index].Selected = true;
                    label3.Text = label3.Text + " " + item.Index.ToString();
                }
            }      
`
none of my records in the dataview gets selected, label3 does have the correct indexes which needs to be selected...

Comment: comments with nice formatting seems to be a problem ;)

Answer (score 51):

In Visual Basic, do this to select a row in a `DataGridView`; the selected row will appear with a highlighted color but note that the cursor position will not change:

```
Grid.Rows(0).Selected = True
```

Do this change the position of the cursor:

```
Grid.CurrentCell = Grid.Rows(0).Cells(0)
```

Combining the lines above will position the cursor and select a row. This is the standard procedure for focusing and selecting a row in a `DataGridView`:

```
Grid.CurrentCell = Grid.Rows(0).Cells(0)
Grid.Rows(0).Selected = True
```

Comment: Grid.Rows(0).Cells(0) is very useful in case of grid data longer than the grid display area. The order mentioned above is not necessary, you can swipe the code for row/cell selection [ source: Personally Tested ].

Comment: How to move the grid to selected position? Row is selected but grid position is not on selected row. Manually scrolling shows the selected row. How to force the grid to scroll?

Comment: See that: FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

Comment: Take care that whatever column you reference in `.Cells(x)` is `Columns(x).Visible = True` or it will error. Use [DataGridView.FirstDisplayed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedcell?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_FirstDisplayedCell) to find the first one.

Answer (score 17):

```
DataGridView.Rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
     .Where(x => (int)x.Cells["Id"].Value == pId)
     .ToArray<DataGridViewRow>()[0]
     .Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <GridViewName>.ClearSelection(); ----------------------------------------------------1
 foreach(var item in itemList) -------------------------------------------------------2
 {
    rowHandle =<GridViewName>.LocateByValue("UniqueProperty_Name", item.unique_id );--3
    if (rowHandle != GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)------------------------------------4
    {
        <GridViewName>.SelectRow(rowHandle);------------------------------------ -----5
    }
  }
```

1. Clear all previous selection.
2. Loop through rows needed to be selected in your grid.
3. Get their row handles from grid (Note here grid is already updated with new rows)
4. Checking if the row handle is valid or not.
5. When valid row handle then select it.

Where itemList is list of rows to be selected in the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
datagridview.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];
```

Comment: [`datagridview.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellcollection.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellCollection_Item_System_Int32_) *Gets ... the cell at the provided index location.*  How does this **select a particular range of rows** as requested in the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Select method if you have a datasource:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b51xae2y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Or use linq if you have objects in you datasource

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[index row you want];
dataGridView1.CurrentRow = row;
```

Hope this help!