# How to programatically select first row of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting a row in Datagridview Programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265228/selecting-a-row-in-datagridview-programatically)

I am developing a new desktop application in C# using Windows Forms. In one of my form i put the `DataGridView Control` and i am populating this `dataGridViewControl` Dynamically using my custom functions.

Now after populating the above control, is there any way to programatically select the first row of that `DataGridViewview`. Note: the Selection mode property of this DataGridView is set to "Full row Select"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: if grid is empty throws an error. It's bettere make a check before.
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0) {...}

Comment: this doesnt do anything after applying filter, it just jumps to the last row anyways

Answer (score 5):

**To select one row in winform DataGridView TRY THIS:**

```
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

*It works ..*

Comment: One might need to scroll to selected row to be visible. dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = RowIndex;