# Setting the cell and row pointer in datagrid doesnt work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a form with a `datagrid` that has a list of records from the table. When the user selects one record to edit its value I want to return to the same row (record) in the datagrid and display it as selected. Of course the datagrid should show the new(edited) values.
The code in the `EditButton` does all of it, but the result is not what expected.

```
    private void zButtonEdit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the rowIndex and columnIndex values
        zButtonEdit1.rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        zButtonEdit1.cellIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        // Store the Id of the current record
        zButtonEdit1._id_ = Convert.ToInt16( dataGridView1["id_lice", zButtonEdit1.rowIndex].Value.ToString());
        // Open the Editform with required data for that ID 
        Lice frmLice = new Lice(zButtonEdit1.UIB, zButtonEdit1._id_);
        frmLice.ShowDialog();
        // When editing is finished, refresh the grid with new values
        refresh_controls();
        //Set the current record pointer (or row pointer) to the record that was edited
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[zButtonEdit1.rowIndex].Cells[zButtonEdit1.cellIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

This is what I get [Datagrid on Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHQ3m.jpg)
Its obvious that I changed only the selection but I have no idea how to change `row` (record) pointer.

Comment: You're setting Selected = true on a cell, to set it on the row, call it on the row: `this.dataGridView1.Rows[zButtonEdit1.rowIndex].Selected = true` Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265228/selecting-a-row-in-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: I tried that first, but the result is similar, only now is the row selected not a cell, but the record pointer didnt change. I can post the picture with that if you like or need it.

Comment: ah, sorry, I misunderstood, I think this is what you want: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[YourColumn,YourRow];` info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc4fsbf5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thank you that worked! How can I upvote your answer there are no options for that in the comments.

Comment: @SilentStorm why don't you write the solution as an answer so the Zed McJack can accept it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

To set the current selected cell:

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[YourColumn,YourRow];
```

Info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc4fsbf5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1