# How to keep the selected row in a DataGridView after updating c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to keep the selected row in a DataGridView after updating?

I hope that the last cell selected will remain after updating the data

Comment: Welcome to SO Dante. In order to help you, we need a sample of what you have tried so far to solve your problem. Could you show us your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265228/19700043

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.